Replicate a Dynamic Form's Conditional Rendering in a L:WC Record Edit Form
A Custom Object has been converted to use Dynamic Forms, and the admin has implemented conditional rendering for several fields e.g. only show field b if field a = 'Hospital'
This conditional logic also works for new records - e.g. if they select Hospital for field a on the new form, field b then appears as a required field, but is otherwise invisible and not required.
Is there any way to replicate that on a LWC Record Form without just totally replicating that logic with a bunch of lwc if statements? And obviously, that won't then be aligned with the form if someone changes it.
I see nothing in the lwc form docs to indicate a way to do it, and nothing in the ui-api docs to suggest there is a way to get at the info, but wondering if someone has found a way to retrieve that logic/and or build it in a LWC Form?

I know this can be done in Aura using:
createRecord : function (component, event, helper) {
    var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
    createRecordEvent.setParams({
        "entityApiName": "Contact"
    });
    createRecordEvent.fire();
}

Link to article: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:createRecord/documentation
